# How can I use Tensorflow to make cellular automata?

Tags: tensorflow, cellular-automata

Knowing that Tensorflow is good for working with matrices, would I be able to use Tensorflow to create a cellular automata? And would this offer a great deal of speed over just coding it in Python?

Are there any tutorials or websites that could point me in the right direction to use Tensorflow for more general purpose computing than machine learning (for example, simulations)?

If so, could someone help point me in the right direction to the type of Tensorflow commands I would need to learn to make this program? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TensorFlow implementation is likely to offer an improvement in execution time, especially if executed by GPU, since CA can be executed in parallel. See: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/320/67726.

A starting point for TensorFlow in general might be the official [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide) and [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs), which do go beyond just machine learning. Also available are two tutorials on non-ML examples: [Mandelbrot Set](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/non-ml/mandelbrot), [Partial Differential Equations](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/non-ml/pdes).

While TensorFlow is usually mentioned in the context of machine learning, it is worth noting [that](https://www.tensorflow.org/):

> TensorFlow™ is an open source software library for **high performance
>   numerical computation**. Its flexible architecture allows easy
>   deployment of computation across a variety of platforms (CPUs, GPUs,
>   TPUs), and from desktops to clusters of servers to mobile and edge
>   devices.

---

**Edit**: [here](https://github.com/conceptacid/conv2d_life)'s an implementation and a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820020958/http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson9/) about Conway's Game of Life using TF.